# How to redirect all non login visitors to specific page in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I am building a website in which user must login to view to pages. I have create a login page. I want to redirect to traffic to that page if they are not logged in.

Answer (score 0):

I do not quite understand the functionality you need,
But you can do this php hard redirect (write in funct):

```
add_action( 'the_post', 'is_user_not_logged_do_redirect',9999);
function is_user_not_logged_do_redirect() {
    global $post;
    $page_register_id = 5566; // set your register page ID;
    $login_page_id = 5567; // set your login page ID;
    $redirect_code = 302; // redirect type;
    if(!is_user_logged_in() && $post && $post->ID != $page_register_id && 
    $login_page_id != $post->ID){
        wp_redirect(get_permalink($page_register_id),$redirect_code);
    }
}
```

P.S. this redirect not better way for SEO and Google =)

Comment: My requirement is if anyone who are not logged in, visit any page, must redirect to custom login page.

Comment: Are you sure this will work? `the_post` is pretty late in the execution order.  `wp_redirect` must be used before headers are sent.

Comment: @GauravTikhile - I tested it on one of my project. It work same as you write, just change page id to yours =)

Comment: @HowardE - Yes, and no) Ther are no headers in WP standart at "the_post". Maybe some plugins not using this rules. It possible to do redirect with JS code including, but that not good =)